# Data not delete using sqllite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How to delete specific data using sqlite database via android.

```
db.delete("tbl_rmd", "rmd_typ = ? ", new String[]{id});
```

> error : index not found

Comment: yes java language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must determine whether or not the data exists in the sqlite database.

```java
 public boolean checkIfRecordExist(String tableName, String columnName, String fieldValue) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String Query = "Select * from " + tableName + " where " + columnName + " =? ";
        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(Query, new String[]{fieldValue});
        if (cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        cursor.close();
        return true;
    }
```

now modify your code like this...

```java
if (checkIfRecordExist("tbl_rmd", "rmd_typ", id)) {
    db.delete("tbl_rmd", "rmd_typ = ? ", new String[]{id});
}
```

Comment: Why? If the id does not exist in the table then nothing will be deleted.

Comment: Your error is `error : index not found`. It means your data is not found. But you want to delete it.

Comment: No, this error does not mean that the row is not found. SQLite does not throw an error when a deletion does not succeed because the row does not exist.

Comment: in my case that working for me

Comment: It is working but it is not necessary and for sure does not solve the OP's problem.